# How to automate flooded area calculation and make report using PyQgis?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, excel, hydrology

I have 3 shapefiles with me. They are a flooded layer, District layer and Village layer. To estimate flooding village wise, I have to do intersecting the features and get the layer. Then I calculate the flooded layer.

Raw village shapefile contains the attributes '**Village_Name**' and '**Area**'.

District layer contains '**District_name**' and '**Revenue_Circle**'

After intersecting the area for the flooded layer is calculated as '**flooded_area**'. So the intersected layer will have '**District_nam**','**Revenue_Circle**', '**Village_area**' and '**flooded_Area**'.

After doing all these I have to convert all the attributes to excel file and using Pivot table all the data need to be sorted district wise. In the excel I have to remove underscore, change the field name, adding a percentage of the village area got flooded and display summation at the last and all these are done in separate sheets for each district.

Is there any automatic workflow for this if I have to do this every day?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to start with. I have used only pivot table in excel so that I don't have to sort and copy one by one from excel. I believe it should be automatic. That is why I asked here how to do that. It would be really helpful if you can share some tips.

Comment: I suggest you try to do this workflow in QGIS. When you know the workflow works you can use QGIS model builder https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html to automate it or alternatively use Pyqgis https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: I can try the model builder but how about the excel chart. Can we make the excel chart using the attribute information, and modify and add summation as the final output for separate districts?

Comment: Can you try to use the data ploty plugin to see if it can be done. I think it is a processing plugin so it should be possible to use it within model builder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could use it to plot graphs. But still my problem for making database is not sorted yet. Final output should be in formated sheets for individual district.

Comment: I suggest you create the model in QGIS and export it as python script. When it’s a python script you could use openpxl to create the graphs you need. We have done something similar

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Graphical Modeler* to automate this.

You can do the statistics in QGIS (with for instance *Statistics by categories*).

After running the model, the QGIS *Report* (or *Atlas*) tool will help you create a report (one page per village, with maps and statistics). See https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_reports.html.